# How to sequentially join two data frames using `dplyr` functions?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to sequentially join data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
a <- 1:6
b <- rnorm(length(a))

df <- data.frame(a = a)
```

My intended outcome is

```
df_target <- data.frame(a = a, b = b)
df_target

  a          b
1 1 -0.6264538
2 2  0.1836433
3 3 -0.8356286
4 4  1.5952808
5 5  0.3295078
6 6 -0.8204684
```

First, I want to "add" column b of the following data frame (the first 3 entries of vector `b` that belong to the first 3 entries of `a`:

```
df_to_add1 <- data.frame(a = a[1:3], b = b[1:3])
```

This can be achieved by `left_join` from the `dplyr` package.

```
df1 <- left_join(df, df_to_add1)
df1

  a          b
1 1 -0.6264538
2 2  0.1836433
3 3 -0.8356286
4 4         NA
5 5         NA
6 6         NA
```

Next, I want to do attach the remainder, i.e., the last 3 entries of `b` that belong to the last 3 entries of `a`:

```
df_to_add2 <- data.frame(a = a[4:6], b = b[4:6])
```

If I use `left_join` again, nothing is added

```
left_join(df1, df_to_add2)

Joining, by = c("a", "b")
  a          b
1 1 -0.6264538
2 2  0.1836433
3 3 -0.8356286
4 4         NA
5 5         NA
6 6         NA
```

If I use `full_join`, then this does what I want, but has duplicate rows:

```
full_join(df1, df_to_add2)

Joining, by = c("a", "b")

  a          b
1 1 -0.6264538
2 2  0.1836433
3 3 -0.8356286
4 4         NA
5 5         NA
6 6         NA
7 4  1.5952808
8 5  0.3295078
9 6 -0.8204684
```

I can get the target by removing the duplicate rows:

```
df_tmp <- full_join(df1, df_to_add2)
df_tmp <- df_tmp[complete.cases(df_tmp),]
df_tmp

  a          b
1 1 -0.6264538
2 2  0.1836433
3 3 -0.8356286
7 4  1.5952808
8 5  0.3295078
9 6 -0.8204684
```

This doesn't seem like the right solution, is there a better way to join the data frames sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the _add* tables first.

```
library(dplyr)

result1 <- full_join(df_to_add1, df_to_add2) %>% full_join(df)
identical(result1, df_target)
## [1] TRUE
```

or just:

```
result2 <- full_join(df_to_add1, df_to_add2)
identical(result2, df_target)
## [1] TRUE
```

or

```
result3 <- df %>% right_join(df_to_add1) %>% full_join(df_to_add2)
identical(result3, df_target)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

The inputs from the question wihtout the intermediate text so it's easier to copy and paste:

```
# inputs
set.seed(1)
a <- 1:6
b <- rnorm(length(a))
df <- data.frame(a = a)
df_to_add1 <- data.frame(a = a[1:3], b = b[1:3])
df_to_add2 <- data.frame(a = a[4:6], b = b[4:6])

# desired
df_target <- data.frame(a = a, b = b)
```

Comment: This isn't possible in what I actually want to do, since those are generated in a for loop (so when I add `df_to_add1`, I don't know `df_to_add2` yet; and when I want to add `df_to_add2`, then `df_to_add1` will no longer exist). So this should be done sequentially in some way.

Comment: Can't you just save df_to_add1 and df_to_add2 rather than add  them and then do the joining after the loop?

Comment: No, iterations are over multiple variables and many steps. I assumed there would be a simple way to use the dplyr functions to do what I want. There is one large "results" data frame to which I want to sequentially add new results when computed in the loop

Comment: See third  approach just added.

Comment: If that is still not what you want I think the queestion needs to be clarified since all three of these answers give the required target.